# Launching interval after updating props in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to fire interval after backend data will come in as a prop. 
Take a look at this chunk of code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getAdvert } from "../../actions/advert";
import './_advert.scss';

class Advert extends Component {
  state = { counter: 0 };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { getAdvert } = this.props;

    getAdvert();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { counter } = this.state;

    this.bannerInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({ counter: counter === Object.keys(nextProps.banners).length - 1 ? 0 : counter + 1 });
    }, 1000) 
  }

  render() {
    const { banners } = this.props;
    const { counter } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="advert__container">
        <img src={banners[counter] && banners[counter].image_url} alt="advert" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ banners }) => {
  return { banners };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getAdvert: () => dispatch(getAdvert())
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Advert);
```

So as you can see I tried to run it within componentWillReceiveProps method as I thought it might be proper place to be dependent on incoming props. But that won't work. I will run only once and interval will be repeating the same value.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

ComponentWillReceive props is extremely dangerous used in this way. You are istantiating a new interval every time a props is received without storing and canceling the previous one.
Also is not clear how do you increment counter, as I see the increment in your ternary will not increase the counter value incrementaly.

```js
// This is an example, the lifeCylce callback can be componentWillReceive props
componentDidMount() { 
   const intervalId = setInterval(this.timer, 1000);
   // store intervalId in the state so it can be accessed later:
   this.setState({intervalId: intervalId});
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   // use intervalId from the state to clear the interval
   clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
}

timer = () => {
   // setState method is used to update the state with correct binding
   this.setState({ currentCount: this.state.currentCount -1 });
}
```

Comment: You're right! But my question was a bit more specific, I need to run interval just after I will get props. In my code you can see: Object.keys(nextProps.banners).length. The counter is dependent on what it gets from backend

Comment: I understand your needs but be careful, this is an anti-pattern. Take 5 minutes to read this from react blog: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html. The best solution is to lift the counter state management in upper component and get rid of componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: I understand that but still my issue persist, ie. how to set interval with setState which is dependent on incoming data

Comment: You do not have to wait for data to be passed as props to set a state, that's the point. Aside this, the approach is the same as plain javscript. If you provide a snippet in your question with a minimum scaffolding of your situation I can be more specific.